# Extremely confused on router issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I have a Motorola Cable Modem from my ISP for Ethernet and Wi-Fi broadcast, and since my girlfriend's Wii U will not see a 5 GHz signal, I decided to order an ASUS RT-1200 dual-band router to broadcast at both 2.4 and 5. Wi-Fi and everything works. That brings me to my problem. When I have my computer's Ethernet cable plugged into the MOTO router, I cannot access the Internet, nor can I access the router at 192.168.0.1, which is the set gateway. I was able to access it previously by having the computer directly connected to the ASUS router, which I could then access the ASUS at 192.168.50.1 and the MOTO at 192.168.0.1. Being connected to the MOTO router gave me speeds of 200 Mbps, whereas the ASUS gives me 90 Mbps. I'm not sure where I went wrong but now I cannot access the Internet through the MOTO when my computer's Ethernet is plugged into it. My Xbox is plugged into it and works great, but it as well cannot access the router through the gateway. I am at a complete loss here. No IP conflicts, I don't want to sacrifice speed for that damn Wii U p.o.s..

The last thing I remember doing before running into this problem was killing the broadcast from the MOTO router to avoid interference and I reserved the IP for the ASUS router for it to be able to have only, its gateway. Which, after killing the Wi-Fi, is really not needed, but it's one of the last things I remember doing.

Any ideas?

Comment: What Motorola cable gateway do you have that only does 5GHz Wi-Fi?

Comment: The router is  on another subnet then your pc, additionally most Motorola modems only have a single LAN port.  Your router is connected to the subnet the modem issues but the modem is not connected to the routers subnet.  In other words it's not shocking you can't connect to your router if your connected to your modem.  So this means you can't connect both your router and your pc to the modem.  Your download speed difference is because your modem likely has 1GB ports and your router doesn't

Comment: The simplest solution to this problem is to perform a Reset on both devices

Comment: The motorola is a modem/router hybrid. It's an sbg6850

Comment: If you have additional information to provide to clarify your question, and ***especially*** if your situation has changed radically since you posted the question, please do not tack on the updates as comments — [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is some basic network troubleshooting.  Starting with your device and work forward to the Internet.

```
  Ping localhost
  ping default gateway
  ping 8.8.8.8
```

If you can ping these things then your problem is not connectivity but DNS. Which is often a problem.  Go to your adapter settings and in the dns put 8.8.8.8 which is Google's dns server.

Comment: you know what? I literally left my computer plugged into the motorola all night and when I got on this morning, i forgot "thought it was still plugged into the asus" and now the internet is working again... and i can access it at the default gateway. Weirdest thing I've ever seen.

Comment: and now I can't access the ASUS router through its gateway, it's like it went backwards which I'm 100% cool with.

Comment: I would suggest to break things down into segments.  Start with the device closest to the internet and work back.  Plug your  computer in to the ISP's router, make sure you network card is set to dhcp.  go into administrative command line (right click on the command line icon and click run as admin) type in IPCONFIG /RELEASE  then IPCONFIG /RENEW then IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS then IPCONFIG /REGISTERDNS  then PING 8.8.8.8 if that works PING GOOGLE.COM...  if that works connect the  ASUS RT-1200 in the same port your computer was plugged into and  power cycle the  ASUS RT-1200.

Comment: Give the  ASUS RT-1200 a few minutes to get configured and then plug your computer into one it's ports and repeat the previous steps.